# Sorcery и trailblazer-operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

Пытаюсь сделать аутентификацию не в контроллере, а в операции.
Контроллер:

```
module Web
module Bootcamp
class OauthsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login, raise: false

  def oauth
    login_at(params[:provider])
  end

  def callback
    provider = params[:provider]
    result = Ops::Developer::Authenticate.(resource_params)
    if result.success?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged in from #{provider.titleize}"
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Failed to login from #{provider.titleize}"
    end
  end

  private

  def resource_params
    params.permit(:provider)
  end
end
end
end
```

Операция:

```
module Ops
module Developer
class Authenticate < BaseOperation
  step :login!
  failure :create!

  private

  def login!(options, **)
    @user = login_from(options)
  end

  def create!(options, **)
    @user = create_from(options) { |user| user.roles = ['developer'] }
    reset_session
    auto_login(@user)
  end
end
end
end
```

Хелперы sorcery отказываются работать, попытка подключения через include Sorcery - ничего не дает. Может ли кто подсказать, в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Ну, инклюдить, вероятнее всего, нужно не `Sorcery`, а `Sorcery::Controller`. Начать стоит с этого. А дальше, возможно, отладчик вас доведёт.

Comment: Да, хелперы подключились, но из operation нет доступа к сессиям, соответственно, они не работают. С этим, видимо, уже ничего не сделать.

Comment: Ну, не факт. Duck typing на что. Но похоже, что Sorcery задуман как прибитый гвоздями к контроллерам. Даже если можно адаптировать, может быть проще написать заново.